# Error in hist.default(x = aumento$PreuAm2) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que trata de importar un archivo csv en RadioStudio, para realizar un histograma con una de sus columnas.

**library(readr)**

```
aumento <- read.csv("E:\\FORMACION\\ESTADÍSTICA\\vendes_pac1_P_15_2.csv")
```

**View(aumento)**

```
my_data_num <- as.double(aumento)
```

`hist.default(aumento$PreuAm2)` pero el error viene aquí, los valores son numéricos, pero no entiendo por qué me devuelve el error de que no.

Comment: Bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: ¿Estás segura que `aumento$PreuAm2` es numérico? Revisalo con `str(aumento$PreuAm2)`